# Java Swing Library - I cannot get my components to draw, any ideas?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, mouselistener

I'm trying to figure out how to redraw a panel on mouse click. I can capture the mouse clicks just fine, but cannot for the life of me get the component to draw. This is a simplified test class I setup for simplicity. My Test class exteds JComponent.

Any ideas?

Here's my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Point Capture Test");
        frame.setContentPane(new Test().panelMain);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Here's my Test constructor:

```
 public Test() {

        mPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panelMain, e.getPoint());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panelMain, "clicked "+ e.getSource() + " at " + e.getPoint());

                 //removed a bunch of stuff here that captures the clicked coordinates so I can use them to draw lines on the panel

                repaint();
            }
        });

    }
```

Here's my Test paintComponent method:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (this.mClicks > 2) { //draw polygon
            Polygon polyTest = new Polygon();

            for (Point point : this.mPntPoints){
                polyTest.addPoint(point.x, point.y);
            }

            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.fill(polyTest);
            g2.draw(polyTest);
        }

        //just added this as a test and it doesn't draw either
        g2.drawLine(10, 30, 20, 40);

}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: You've missed `super.paintComponent(g);`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad You're right - that's it!